# Check If String Contains any Of the Word From Given List

Tags: android

Check if the string contains any of the words from the given list of string. Here's what I've done so far:

```
private void text_type(){
 String input_data = kw_url_holder.getText().toString();
    String[] words = {"google", "bing"};
 if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(input_data) & input_data.contains("google")){
     Toast.makeText(YTTags.this, "It's URL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
 else{
     Toast.makeText(YTTags.this, "It's Word",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}
```

This code checks if String is Word or URL. In the URL, I want to check if the URL contains list of words. I've used mydata.contains() but it only checks one single word.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public static boolean containsArray(String input_data, String[] words) {
    return Arrays.stream(words).anyMatch(input_data::contains);
}
```

and your if clause

```
if(URLUtil.isValidUrl(input_data) & containsArray(input_data, words)){
    Toast.makeText(YTTags.this, "It's URL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex, will work on all android versions, developing in (java 7/8):-

1- convert your sting array to list (or better if you start with List, arrays are immutable):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(words);
```

2- define your string matcher method:

```
public static boolean isWordFoundInList (String wordToMatch, List<String> list) {
    // convert list to delimited string
    String wordsToMatchDelimited = String.join("|", list);
    return Pattern.compile(wordsToMatchDelimited, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
               .matcher(wordToMatch)
               .find();
}
```

You can test it in an online java compiler here:
[Compile and Execute Java Online](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php)